# Redirect not working in express js when the html file is present

Tags: express

I was trying to do a redirect in express.js when the user submits a form with the below code.

```
app.post('/thank-you', function(req, res){
    res.cookie('form_filled' , 'true');
    res.redirect('/thank-you.html');

 });
```

This code is working fine, redirecting to the thank-you.html file. I also want to check if the cookie(form_filled) is present on a GET request to thank-you.html. The code is as follows.

```
app.get("/thank-you.html", function(req, res) {
    //Condition to check the cookie
    res.redirect('/'); //If cookie not present
  });
```

I haven't written the code for checking cookie, just tried with the above code to verify the redirection first. But it's not working.

Trying with the below code works where there is no thanks.html file in the directory.

```
app.post('/thank-you', function(req, res){
    res.cookie('form_filled' , 'true');
    res.redirect('/thanks.html');

 }); 

app.get("/thanks.html", function(req, res) {
    console.log("Test");
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Comment: did you try redirecting to /index.html instead of "/" ?

Comment: Yeah I tried with that too - not working. The issue is only when there is a corresponding html file in the directory. Even the console.log doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this post I think this will help you out. Try using sendFile or views like ejs, pug, hbs for rendering html files.

[Post about rendering html files in express js](https://codeforgeek.com/render-html-file-expressjs/)

Check the cookie inside the route, also change the routes too. For example change /index.html to /index like that.